# как при скроле вставлять в адресную строку ID что бы страница не лагала?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

я при скроле страницы в `window.location.hash` вставляю **hash**  соответствующий id блока до которого доскролил, и в адресной строке он появляется но при этом все лагае особенно при скроле вверх, а без этого кода все норм

```
    if ( $(document).scrollTop() > refElement.position().top) {
        window.location.hash = this.hash;
    }
```

реально ли убрать лаги ?
если честно то даже не знаю как сформулировать вопрос (((

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");

        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();

    $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
            //console.log(this.hash)
            /*  решение проблемы  */
            if ( $(document).scrollTop() > refElement.position().top) {
                window.location.hash = this.hash;
            }

        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
            // window.location.hash = this.hash;
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
 body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: fixed;
  background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
 }
 .light-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  position: fixed;
  background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
 }
 #menu-center {
  width: 980px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 #menu-center ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
 }
 #menu-center ul li a{
  padding: 32px 40px;
 }
 #menu-center ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 -4px;
  display: inline;

 }
 .active, #menu-center ul li a:hover  {
  font-family:'Droid Sans', serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  padding: 32px 40px;

 }
 a {
  font-family:'Droid Sans', serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 72px;
 }
 #home {
  background-color: #286090;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 #portfolio {
  background: gray;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
 }
 #about {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
 }
 #contact {
  background-color: rgb(154, 45, 45);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
 }
</style>

<div class="m1 menu">
 <div id="menu-center">
  <ul>
   <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>

   </li>
   <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>

   </li>
   <li><a href="#about">About</a>

   </li>
   <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="home"></div>
<div id="portfolio"></div>
<div id="about"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `window.history.pushState`. Но это может не решить проблему.

Почитать о нем можно [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

Самое действенное на мой взгляд, это поставить `timeout`. Дело в том что событие `scroll` срабатывает очень часто.

1) создайте переменную, например `timer`

2) оберните ваш код в `timeout`

```
// обнуляете таймер
clearTimeout(timer)
// запускаете таймаут
timer = setTimeout(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    if ( $(document).scrollTop() > refElement.position().top) {
        // меняете хэш
        window.location.hash = this.hash;
    }
}, 50)
```